# How to add two spaces before every line in a string YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want the config to show up with 2 spaces before each line.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    filename: file1
    a: aaa
    config: |-
              missingok
              daily
              compress
              rotate 4
              create
              dateext
              dateformat -%d%m%Y
              dateyesterday
  tasks:
  - name: Creating log config file
    copy:
      dest: /{{ filename }}
      content: |
        {{ a }}
        {
        {{ config }}
        }
```

[image]

The spaces show up if I add another line at the beginning of config without any spaces. Putting spaces before the config variable also doesn't work because it only affects the first line (missingok) and the rest would be without any spaces in front.

Comment: dont post pictures of code, just post the code, that way people can replicate your issue and be able to aid you in a solution

Comment: Sorry I have made the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell YAML how many spaces of indentation (relative to the parent level) the block scalar has, e.g.:

```yaml
    config: |2-
        missingok
        daily
        compress
        rotate 4
        create
        dateext
        dateformat -%d%m%Y
        dateyesterday
```

By giving `2` but having 4 spaces relative to `config:`, you'll get two spaces in front of every line.

Answer (score 1):

Given the simplified variables for testing

```yaml
  a: aaa
  config: |-
    missingok
    daily
    compress
```

---

Q: ***"Putting spaces before the config variable doesn't work because it only affects the first line."***

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/file1
        content: |
          {{ a }}
          {
            {{ config }}
          }
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/file1 
aaa
{
  missingok
daily
compress
}
```

A: Use the Jinja filter [*indent*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) and format the output

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/file1
        content: |
          {{ a }}
          {
            {{ config|indent(2) }}
          }
```

gives what you want

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/file1 
aaa
{
  missingok
  daily
  compress
}
```

---

Notes

- Formating the value of a variable, i.e. prepending each line in *config* with 2 more spaces, doesn't have to be the best solution. Make your choice.
- The [Block Indentation Indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8111-block-indentation-indicator) can also solve the problem. For example, you declare the indentation of 2 spaces and prepend each line with 2 more spaces

```yaml
  config: |2-
      missingok
      daily
      compress
```

Then the task

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/file1
        content: |
          {{ a }}
          {
          {{ config }}
          }
```

gives also what you want because each line in *config* starts with 2 spaces

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/file1 
aaa
{
  missingok
  daily
  compress
}
```

- Credit to @Jefferson. I wonder why this post was deleted.